# how to retry when returning 486 sipp scenarios

Tags: sip, asterisk, pjsip, freeswitch, sofia-sip

I want to complete this scenarios in **sipp**.

When I make a call, if it return 486 status(busy), It could call pause a while, then continue recalling.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a label and "next" attribute. Something like this:

```
<label id="10" />

...

<recv response="486" optional="true" next="10" />
  <pause milliseconds="1000" />
</recv>
```

Hope this helps